# Gravel bike vs hybrid bike speed

Tags: hybrid-bike, gravel

I saw a video on youtube where a test showed road bike about 7% faster than gravel bike.  How does gravel bike compare to a hybrid bike on purely paved road speed wise?

I have a hybrid now and mostly ride on paved roads just wondering if "upgrading" to gravel would be pointless if it's not faster.

Comment: Probably too many factors to compare.  Differences between tyres alone are enormous, and if you make every part the same, its really just a difference in the bars/body position between a flat-bar and a drop bar bike.

Comment: Agree with Criggie. It very much depends on the specific bikes and body positions you are comparing. Also depends on the speed and terrain. For example a 3kg weight difference won’t make much difference on a flat route at constant speed. Aerodynamic improvements won’t make much difference at slow speed but will be significant at higher speeds.

Comment: @R.Chung yea thats the video